# send email with pdf attachment using logic app : PDF is not getting opened. It got corrupted

Tags: base64, http-post, azure-logic-apps, memorystream, tobase64string

[image]

Sending PDF in Base64 string, using json object. Converted Stream to Base64 before passing. Using Http trigger post for calling logic app
[image]

Email are generated with pdf from logic app but PDF is not opening. Is Base64 content corrupted?

In Logic app, updated attachment content by  ContentBytes => triggerBody()['attachments']?['ContentBytes']  and ContentBytes => base64(triggerBody()['attachments']?['ContentBytes'])

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, you should use the `base64ToBinary` expression:

```
base64ToBinary(triggerBody()['attachments']?['ContentBytes'])
```